# Pandas Groupby: return dict of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to group my dataframe by one of the columns and then return a dictionary that has a list of all of the rows per column value. Is there a fast Pandas idiom for doing this?

Example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['alice', 'bob', 'bob', 'charlie'],
    'transaction_date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'],
    'amount': [50.0, 10.0, 12.0, 13.0]
})
```

Desired output:

```
result = {
  'alice': [Series(transaction_date='2020-01-01', amount=50.0)],
  'bob': [Series(transaction_date='2020-01-01', amount=10.0), Series(transaction_date='2020-01-02', amount=12.0)],
  'charlie': [Series(transaction_date='2020-01-02', amount=53.0)],
}
```

The following approaches do **NOT** work:

```
test.groupby('id').agg(list)
```

- Returns a Dataframe where each column (amount and transaction_date) has a list of values, but that's not what I want. I want the result to be one list of rows / Pandas series per unique grouping column value ('id' value).

```
test.groupby('id').agg(list).to_dict():
{'amount': {'charlie': [13.0], 'bob': [10.0, 12.0], 'alice': [50.0]}, 'transaction_date': {'charlie': ['2020-01-02'], 'bob': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'alice': ['2020-01-01']}}
```

```
test.groupby('id').apply(list).to_dict():
{'charlie': ['amount', 'id', 'transaction_date'], 'bob': ['amount', 'id', 'transaction_date'], 'alice': ['amount', 'id', 'transaction_date']}
```

Comment: This seems like an oddly specific and uncommon format, why would you want this?

Comment: This is another way that I thought of solving this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071112/pandas-merge-and-filter-for-earlier-and-most-recent-value.

I could make the above lookup dictionary, and then apply a function to each row of another dataframe that used binary search to quickly find a matching transaction that met a certain set of transaction_date criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),

```py
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['alice', 'bob', 'bob', 'charlie'],
    'transaction_date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'],
    'amount': [50.0, 10.0, 12.0, 13.0]
})

columns = ['transaction_date', 'amount']

grouped = (test
           .groupby('id')[columns]
           .apply(lambda x: list(x.itertuples(name='Series', index=False))))


print(dict(zip(grouped.index, grouped.values)))

{
    'alice': [Series(transaction_date='2020-01-01', amount=50.0)], 
    'bob': [
        Series(transaction_date='2020-01-01', amount=10.0), 
        Series(transaction_date='2020-01-02', amount=12.0)
    ], 
    'charlie': [Series(transaction_date='2020-01-02', amount=13.0)]
}
```